# Arranging four points as a square

Tags: php, math, geometry

This is prob more of a geometry question, but
I have an array of 4 points (from user input), that could be in any order.
I'm trying to work out a procedure that would return what each point is likely to be, i.e.

```
top left,
top right,
bottom left,
bottom Right
```

I'm working in PHP now, but any help in any language is fine.

{'Ill add what i've got so far in PHP shortly}

*Would this question be better asked on another stackexchange, math maybe?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could sort the points by their x coordinates ascending and if there's a tie, the y coordinate ascending.

The first two points are the "left" side - the one with the greater y is the "top" and the other is "bottom".

The last two points are the "right" side, same deal.

This won't work for a diamond though! (But what's "top-left" on a diamond anyway?)

In general, for a *convex* set of points, you can calculate the centroid (x value is the average of all x values, y value is the average of all y values).

Then, you can calculate the argument (i.e. angle) of the line between the centroid and the point, being [`arctan2`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.atan2.php) of `(y_pt-y_centroid,x_pt-x_centroid)`.

If you then sort the points by their arguments, they'll be in anticlockwise order, with -pi being the West point of the compass, 0 being the East, wrapping around again to +pi being the west point.

Answer (score 1):

You could sort the points first vertically and call the top 2 points top points and the bottom 2 bottom points. Then sort the points horizontally and call the two right-most points right and the other two left. Now you have one of each.

Answer (score 1):

The two-points with the lowest x-values make up the left-side, the other two make up the right.

Same goes for y and top/bottom.